# Making rows of points in dataframe into POLYGON using geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I am trying to finding out if points are in closed polygons (in this question: [Finding if a point in a dataframe is in a polygon and assigning polygon name to point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67910363/finding-if-a-point-in-a-dataframe-is-in-a-polygon-and-assigning-polygon-name-to)) but I realized that there might be another way to do this:

I have this dataframe

```
df=
id     x_zone     y_zone
0  A1  65.422080  48.147850
1  A1  46.635708  51.165745
2  A1  46.597984  47.657444
3  A1  68.477700  44.073700
4  A3  46.635708  54.108190
5  A3  46.635708  51.844770
6  A3  63.309560  48.826878
7  A3  62.215572  54.108190
```

and I  would like to transform this into

```
id     Polygon
0  A1  POLYGON((65.422080, 48.147850), (46.635708,  51.165745), (46.597984,  47.657444), (68.477700,  44.073700))
1  A3  POLYGON((46.635708,54.108190), (46.635708 ,51.844770), (63.309560, 48.826878),(62.215572 , 54.108190))
```

and do the same for points:

```
df1= 

 item   x   y
0     1  50  49
1     2  60  53
2     3  70  30
```

to

```
item   point
0     1  POINT(50,49)
1     2  POINT(60,53)
2     3  POINT(70,30)
```

I have never used geopandas and am a little at a loss here.

My question is thus: How do I get from a pandas dataframe to a dataframe with geopandas attributes?

Thankful for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following to directly get a GeoDataFrame from your df:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=df.groupby('name').apply(
        lambda g: Polygon(gpd.points_from_xy(g['x_zone'], g['y_zone']))
    )
)
```

It first creates a list of points using geopandas' `points_from_xy`, then create a Polygon object from this list.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!!!! It saves me a lot of head-ache...such as this question I just posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918340/appending-geodataframes-does-not-return-expected-dataframe.

Does it work the same way with points?

Comment: Ah indeed I forgot to answer the second part of your question. In this case it's simpler as there's no groupby or Polygon to make, you have `geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1['x'], df1['y']))`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve as follows but you would have to set the right dtype. I know in ArcGIS you have to set the dtype as geometry;

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: 'POLYGON(' + str(tuple(zip(x['x_zone'],x['y_zone'])))+')')
```